# Wordpress fails to load scripts

Tags: wordpress, html5-audio, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm desperately trying to implement the audio player from this tutorial:
https://www.script-tutorials.com/html5-audio-player-with-playlist/
as a wordpress plugin. I need a player I can costumize myself for my website. Noob Alert, I just started taking a look into the rabbithole of customizing wordpress myself, sorry if this was asked before, I searched stackoverflow but I could not find anything that helped.

I downloaded the source from the above mentioned tutorial and created a index.php in the source directory. This is what I've tried:

```
<?php
/**
* Plugin Name: Audio Player
* Description: Just a test Plugin
* Version: 1.0
* Author: rtuz2th
**/

wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-1.7.2.min.js', plugins_url( 'js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js' , __FILE__ ), array('jquery') );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js', plugins_url( 'js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js' , __FILE__ ), array('jquery') ); 
wp_enqueue_style( 'main', plugins_url( 'wp-content/plugins/test/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js' , __FILE__ ) );


function test_shortcode(){
    $player='

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="author" content="Script Tutorials" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />

    <!-- add styles and scripts -->
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="example">

        <div class="player">
            <div class="pl"></div>
            <div class="title"></div>
            <div class="artist"></div>
            <div class="cover"></div>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="play"></div>
                <div class="pause"></div>
                <div class="rew"></div>
                <div class="fwd"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="volume"></div>
            <div class="tracker"></div>
        </div>
    <ul class="playlist hidden">
            <li audiourl="01.mp3" cover="cover1.jpg" artist="Artist 1">01.mp3</li>
            <li audiourl="02.mp3" cover="cover2.jpg" artist="Artist 2">02.mp3</li>
            <li audiourl="03.mp3" cover="cover3.jpg" artist="Artist 3">03.mp3</li>
            <li audiourl="04.mp3" cover="cover4.jpg" artist="Artist 4">04.mp3</li>
            <li audiourl="05.mp3" cover="cover5.jpg" artist="Artist 5">05.mp3</li>
            <li audiourl="06.mp3" cover="cover6.jpg" artist="Artist 6">06.mp3</li>
            <li audiourl="07.mp3" cover="cover7.jpg" artist="Artist 7">07.mp3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
';
    return $player;
}

add_shortcode('test', 'test_shortcode');
?>
```

Instead of the Player being displayed I just get filenames 01.mp3 to 07.mp3 as a bullet list. I've tried debugging and I understand my mistake must be something in the way I adress the js and css scripts, but I've been going through every single tutorial I could find on this and I'm still stuck. Could anybody please get me on track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Here is an error with your code

<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>

In src/href attribute call the relative url like: (if the script is in themes/theme_name/js)
src="<?php echo get_template_ditectory_uri();?>/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js
```

Comment: Okay, I hope I got you right. I've got the copy of the audioplayer source located in wp-content/plugins/audio-player together with my index.php.
I've found this function in the wordpress doc:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_url
and now I reference sources like this:

`src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )();?>/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"> 
</script>`

But when I try to debug this I just get this

`%3C:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Several times. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Okay, I dug in deeper and got it working! Im just referencing source with the full url now. Thank you so much for getting me on track!! At least the player is displayed now, but without functionality and my whole theme is messed up, too, but at least I have a starting point now.

Comment: please check the url path in view source and click them to check if they are working